# android app not identifying Camera properties

Tags: android, android-camera

-In the top of the class i wrote :

```
 import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
```

-When creating a Camera object, it does not identify the next things:

```
Camera c;
Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
Camera c = Camera.open();
```

-I wrote in manifest the following lines:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" 
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
```

Comment: Did you try closing Android Studio and doing a clean and full rebuild of the project?

Comment: Please post your full code.@Elish